# Retrieving all directorie names (relative path)

Tags: php, php5

Just a small code review.
Is there a better way to get all folder names?

```
<?php
$folders = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/myFolder', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ( $folders as $f ) {
    $lastDsPos = strrpos($v, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    $myFolders[] = substr($v, $lastDsPos+1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using SPLs RecursiveIteratorIterator and RecursiveDirectoryIterator? Like this:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->directory), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach($iterator as $path){
    if($path->isDir()){
        $cache = $this->GetInfoArray($path->__toString());
        isset($cache) ? $this->listing['directories'][] = $cache : "";
        unset($cache);
    } else {
        $this->listing['files'][] = $this->GetInfoArray($path->__toString());
    }
}
```

This will leave you with an array with two main nodes: files and directories. I wrote this for a PHP distributed test-and-build-on-commit system and it worked well. More info on the PHP SPL Iterators can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php

By the way, the GetInfoArray is this:

```
private function GetInfoArray($path){
    $d = new SplFileInfo($path);
    if($d->getBasename() == "." || $d->getBasename() == ".."){
        return;
    } else {
        return array(
           "pathname"    => $d->getPathname(),
           "access"      => $d->getATime(),
           "modified"    => $d->getMTime(),
           "permissions" => $d->getPerms(),
           "size"        => $d->getSize(),
           "type"        => $d->getType(),
           "path"        => $d->getPath(),
           "basename"    => $d->getBasename(),
           "filename"    => $d->getFilename()
        );
    }
}
```

In the end, you're left with something like this:

```
$this->listing['files']['smiles.jpg']['pathname'] = "/srv/www/smiles.jpg"
$this->listing['files']['smiles.jpg']['access'] = "1323546894"
$this->listing['files']['smiles.jpg']['modified'] = "2316546521"
$this->listing['files']['smiles.jpg']['permissions'] = "744"
$this->listing['files']['smiles.jpg']['size'] = "12Kb"
$this->listing['files']['smiles.jpg']['type'] = "jpg"
$this->listing['files']['smiles.jpg']['path'] = "/srv/www"
$this->listing['files']['smiles.jpg']['basename'] = "smiles"
$this->listing['files']['smiles.jpg']['filename'] = "smiles.jpg"
```

What the heck, heres the class itself:

```
# Done

class DirectoryReader{
    private $directory;
    private $listing;

    public function __construct($directory){
        try {
            $this->directory = $directory;
            $this->listing = array();
            $this->ListDir();
        } catch(UnexpectedValueException $e){
            die("Path cannot be opened.");
        } catch(RuntimeException $e){
            die("Path given is empty string.");
        }
    }

    public function GetListing(){
        return $this->listing;
    }

    private function ListDir(){
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->directory), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
        foreach($iterator as $path){
            if($path->isDir()){
                $cache = $this->GetInfoArray($path->__toString());
                isset($cache) ? $this->listing['directories'][] = $cache : "";
                unset($cache);
            } else {
                $this->listing['files'][] = $this->GetInfoArray($path->__toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private function GetInfoArray($path){
        $d = new SplFileInfo($path);
        if($d->getBasename() == "." || $d->getBasename() == ".."){
            return;
        } else {
            return array(
               "pathname"    => $d->getPathname(),
               "access"      => $d->getATime(),
               "modified"    => $d->getMTime(),
               "permissions" => $d->getPerms(),
               "size"        => $d->getSize(),
               "type"        => $d->getType(),
               "path"        => $d->getPath(),
               "basename"    => $d->getBasename(),
               "filename"    => $d->getFilename()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

As a further note, you can also just call `scandir($directory)` and filter via `is_dir()` in a `foreach`.

Comment: +1 for the nice snippet, didnt know the DirectoryIterator. But before I check as correct answer. Isn't this a lot of bloat for simply showing the directory names that are inside a given directory?

Comment: @Pinoniq - it is a lot of bloat...like I mentioned, this is a class for a custom built build tool, so some bloat is ok since it only gets used every now and again. Also, this gives you a whole lot more information about the file and directory, than just a listing (gives last accessed time, permissions, etc). Also, it could benefit from some optimization, considering this is the first version of the tool & class

Comment: Also, can just be autoloaded and called via `$dirsAndFiles = (new DirectoryReader($directory))->GetListing();`

Comment: You should create gist ;)

Comment: Here you go @Pinoniq https://gist.github.com/jsanc623/6233664

Comment: also did a quick `microtime()'d` test and average for a directory containing 338 leafs (files + directories), total time taken was  0.009312 - not bad at all